# How can I convert my for loop into a recursive algorithm?

Tags: java, loops, recursion

This is my code that generates any possible permutation in the given length (n) from string s (the abc):

```
public String binary(int n, String str, int i) {
    String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    //i=s.length();
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(str);
        return str;
    }
    if (i == s.length()) {
        System.out.println(str);
        return "";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        binary(n - 1, str + s.charAt(i), i);
    }

    return "";
}
```

My question is: how can I convert my `for` loop into a recursive algorithm? I am not allowed to use any loops in this homework task.

Comment: You must use a for loop.

Comment: Not true, there is a way.

Comment: Ok then, what is it?

Comment: I promise to tell when I find it.

Comment: Ok, I will [tell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37775005/5221149).

Comment: Andreas, you are my sunshine <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it by actually *using* the `i` parameter.

```
private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
public static void binary(int n, String str, int i) {
    if (i == ALPHABET.length())
        return;
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(str);
        return;
    }
    binary(n - 1, str + ALPHABET.charAt(i), 0); // next letter starts at beginning of alphabet
    binary(n, str, i + 1); // do it again using next letter of alphabet
}
```

**TEST**

```
binary(2, "", 0);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
aa
ab
ac
...
az
ba
bb
...
zy
zz
```